# PostgreSQL not using covering index as expected

Tags: postgresql

Given following schema with PostgreSQL 12.3 server

```
create table records
(
    id                           serial                                           primary key,
    number                       varchar(20)                                      not null,
    owner_id                     integer                                          not null,
    state                        varchar(16)    default 'open'::character varying not null,
    created_at                   date,
    updated_at                   date,
    finished_at                  date
)
```

I am performing query which paginates records with stored state and some timestamp attributes.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS)
SELECT "records".*
FROM "records"
WHERE "records"."trashed_at" IS NULL
  AND "records"."owner_id" = 11
  AND "records"."state" IN ('fresh', 'processing')
ORDER BY "records"."created_at" DESC, "records"."number" DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;

=>

 Limit  (cost=1241.09..1447.85 rows=20 width=1326) (actual time=1266.202..26013.831 rows=6 loops=1)
   Output: ....
   Buffers: shared hit=84977 read=132675 dirtied=4
   ->  Index Scan using index_records_on_owner_id_and_created_at_and_number on public.records  (cost=0.56..254588.42 rows=24627 width=1326) (actual time=116.749..26013.765 rows=126 loops=1)
         Output: ......
         Index Cond: (records.owner_id = 14759)
         Filter: ((records.trashed_at IS NULL) AND ((records.state)::text = ANY ('{fresh,processing}'::text[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 228669
         Buffers: shared hit=84977 read=132675 dirtied=4
 Planning Time: 0.682 ms
 Execution Time: 26013.889 ms
(11 rows)
```

Execution time is slow due to buffers read. When they are all in cache, time is reduced to ~300ms.
From EXPLAIN we can see that index `index_records_on_owner_id_and_created_at_and_number` was used. It is defined like

```
create index index_records_on_owner_id_and_created_at_and_number
    on records (owner_id asc, created_at desc, number desc);
```

Notice that planner has really bad estimates (yes, `VACUUM ANALYZE` was performed before explain).

I expected that creating covering index `index_records_optimize_sort_on_created_at_and_number_in` bellow is going to help and will result to Index Scan without filter part. However planner uses only old plan and does not benefit from new index.

```
create index index_records_optimize_sort_on_created_at_and_number_in
    on records (owner_id asc, created_at desc, number desc)
    include (state)
    where (trashed_at IS NULL);
```

I believed that this is perferct candidate for covering index as all filter/sort attributes are included insige index.

I can create another index, which helps this particular query. But there is a ceavant. From UI, I allow to select different states. So index suits single scenario, but there are multiple state combinations.

```
create index index_records_optimize_sort_on_created_at_with_where
    on records (owner_id asc, created_at desc, number desc)
    where (trashed_at IS NULL AND records.state IN ('fresh', 'processing'));
```

Am I missing something in the docs? Can single index modified so planner will use it? I have spend many hours in docs / cybertec blog (thanks for it!), but cannot make any progress.

Answer (score 0):

Index only scans are not all that clever.  You are, by the use of `*`, selecting the `trashed_at` column, but that column is not available in the index. Now, it could synthesize the value to return for trashed_at based on the `WHERE` clause restriction, but it is not clever enough to do that.

So instead, it is just not willing to use an index-only scan, which defeats the purpose of the "covering" index (that is, it is not *really* a covering index).  Either put trashed_at into the indexed columns list, or enumerate all the columns you need to return and don't put trashed_at into that list.